# Grouping two columns find differences

Tags: excel, match, grouping, difference

I want group like values in Column A and Compare all values in Column B and mark all of the rows for Column A if at least one value is different in column b. Example.

```
Column A ######### Column B ############### Result ##
1135220C      Private IP (PIP)               FALSE
1135220C      Private IP (PIP)               FALSE
1135220C      Ethernet                       FALSE
1136484C      Ethernet                       TRUE
1136484C      Private IP (PIP)               TRUE
1139141C      Private IP (PIP)               TRUE
1139141C      Calling Card, Private IP (PIP) TRUE
1140007C      Ethernet                       FALSE
1328791C      Private IP (PIP)               TRUE
1328791C      Private IP (PIP)               TRUE
1328791C      Private IP (PIP), VoIP         TRUE
1228800C      Internet                       FALSE
1228800C      Internet                       FALSE
1228800C      Internet                       FALSE
```

Comment: I don't see how 1136484C is False and 1139141C is true?

Comment: Does your result column have any relation to your question? If so -- you haven't said what the relation is or adequately described where those true/false values come from. And what do you mean when you say you want to "mark" a row? Highlight it? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry John - I had an error in my example.  I corrected.

Comment: The True and False is what I need to get to I put them there as an example of my end state...right now I only have Column A & B.  I need to mark Column C with some indicator (0, 1, #N/A, Not Found, something)      I want to know given value in Column a, where at least one of the associated values don't match the others in the Column B set for the Given Value in Column A.  The use case is I am trying to see where there is a change of product (Column b) from order to order for the location (Column A).

Comment: Problem solved:  A co-worker of mine came up with a solution using IF and Vlookup.IF(VLOOKUP(Column A,'for member 1 of group' (unique set of the data)!A$1:B$22000,2 (Column B),FALSE)=Column B,TRUE,FALSE).    I will then count Column A with False to show how many changed from record to record.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: A co-worker of mine came up with a solution using IF and Vlookup.

```
IF(VLOOKUP(Column A,'for member 1 of group' (unique set of the data)!A$1:B$22000,
2 (Column B),FALSE)=Column B,TRUE,FALSE).
```

I will then count Column A with False to show how many changed from record to record. –